# Does the first column of /sys/block/<dev>/stat refer to the number of read system calls?

Tags: linux, device-tree, sysfs

The [doc](https://docs.kernel.org/block/stat.html#block-layer-statistics-in-sys-block-dev-stat) says that this data refers to `number of read I/Os processed`, and its units is `requests`, does the `requests` refer to the number of read system calls on this device?

Comment: "*Does the first column of ...*" - Think you mean 'row' of the table, which actually describes just a field in a line. "*does the `requests` refer to the number of read system calls on this device*" - Seems like a reasonable interpretation. Did you try any experiments to see how that value changes?